# scala Future deadlock - fixed 4-thread pool

Tags: scala, deadlock, future

[Digging around concurrecny](https://github.com/Sergey80/scala-samples/blob/master/src/main/scala/concurrency/DeadLockSample1.scala)(again).

Q1: Why it is dead-lock?

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4))

val futures = List( Future{1} )

val result: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(futures)

Await.ready(result, Duration.Inf)
```

I expected to have similar behaviour when I have 5 future/threads in the pool (more than 4).

Comment: it doesn't even compiler; second line causes ambiguous implicit error

Comment: Code works with no deadlock for me. Is it the actual code?

Comment: for me even one line code:  Await.ready( Future{1}, Duration.Inf) ends up with deadlock. maybe I should reboot :) silly

Comment: Unless you threadpool never has a thread for you, that cannot be true. In this example, it must return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's not a deadlock.
I think the main thread is waiting for the thread pool to exit.
try calling `.shutdown()` of the executor service.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Await, Future}

object DeadLockSample1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val pool =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(pool)
    Future{1}
    pool.shutdown() // without this, it won't exit.
  }
}
```

Comment: ogm. then I'n not crazzy.